# Mysql Left Join with Sum Criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to create a report which will show customers who have an outstanding account balance however I cant seem to get it to work using a left join.

I have 3 tables - customers, purchases and payments and i'm trying to display customers whose total purchases cost less payments is greater than 0.

So far, I have the following query:

```
mysqli_query("SELECT customers.name as name, SUM(purchases.cost) as cost, SUM(payments.paymentamount) as payments FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN purchases ON purchases.customerid = customers.id 
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.customerid = customers.id 
WHERE (cost - payments) > 0 
GROUP BY customers.id");
```

Can anyone see why this isn't working?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate each total on a subquery for every `customerID` to avoid incorrect result.

```
SELECT  a.*,
        COALESCE(b.totalPurchase , 0) - COALESCE(c.totalPayment , 0) AS Balance
FROM    customers a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  customerid, SUM(cost) totalPurchase
            FROM    purchases
            GROUP   BY customerid
        ) b ON a.ID = b.customerID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  customerid, SUM(paymentamount) totalPayment
            FROM    payments
            GROUP   BY customerid
        ) c ON a.ID = c.customerID
WHERE   COALESCE(b.totalPurchase , 0) - COALESCE(c.totalPayment , 0) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks JW. I almost have it working however when I try to display the results using while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1)), then $row1['totalPurchase'] and $row1['totalPayment'] both return 0. Any ideas?

Comment: it will return `0` when a customer has no records fro `Purchases` table or `Payments` table. Can you give sample records? `:)`

Comment: Thanks. Im not sure how to post snippets but you are correct - in a lot of cases, customers will always have a purchase but may have made any payments. However, my report is showing 0 for all customers on purchases and payments even when they have instances of both. Thanks!

Comment: see this example, it works on the demostration http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/040d0/2

Comment: Problem solved! The answer above didn't have COALESCE (b.totalPurchase , 0) totalPurchase and COALESCE(c.totalPayment , 0) totalPayment in the initial select which the fiddle did. I added these in and it's now working. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: you're welcome `:D` i thought you are not interested on the values that why i only projected the calculated one. `:)`